# Does the iCalendar format support more than one event at the same time?

Tags: php, icalendar, rfc2445

I apologise if this is on the wrong StackExchange site. I suppose it could go to Apple SE, but I'm more interested in the intricacies of `.ical` files, not the app itself as I want to parse the files with PHP.

I'm writing a web app with a calendar feature. It needs to load `.ical` files and display appointments grouped into half hour slots.

**Do `.ical` files support multiple events at the same time?** When it comes to writing code to add events, the start time will be rounded to the nearest 30 minutes, so two events could have the same start time. Is this permitted in `.ical` files, as well as being parsed properly by PHP parsers? I'm only really interested in iCal files of the recent or most popular versions.

I'm guessing the answer is "yes", seeing as events have their own `DTSTAMP`, `DTSTART` and `DTEND` properties, but I want to be sure that a parser (in PHP) can cope with this.

Comment: Since iCal uses the iCalendar file format (duh), which is actually a widely-used format for calendar applications, I think your question is fine here.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for the edit. I was referring more to the `.ical` extension than the app itself. And yes, it's obvious that iCal uses the iCalendar format. Thanks for clearing that up :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is, as defined in the [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1) (which does not say anything about disallowing it)